# How to escape html characters in LESS?

Tags: css, less

I was wondering how escape the + symbol using LESS?

My code so far(no luck):

```
 &.blocked {
    color:#fff;
    &:after {
      content:"\+";
    }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: There is no difference to CSS escaping

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
&.blocked {
    color:#fff;
    &:after {
      content:'\002B';
    }
 }
```

Also, here's [a handy link for escaping in CSS](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys, but I found a workaround where I don't need to use any characters at all. Solution: A span with a background-color and a solid border